# Access Violation Exception when trying to access bstrVal field of variant object

Tags: c++, wmi

I'm trying to get hardware information using WMI and the (Win32_Processor) class.
When I try to access the "Name" property of this class through a IWbemClassObject I get the Name of the cpu and the program executes without error.

However when I try to access any other property("NumberOfCores" for example) I get an "Access Violation" exception.

Here is a part my code:

```
    HRESULT hres;
    IWbemClassObject* pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;

    // pSvc is a IWbemServices object.

    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
           bstr_t("WQL"),
           bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor"),
           WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
           NULL,
           &pEnumerator);

    
    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        hres = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1,
            &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if (0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

        VARIANT vtProp;

        VariantInit(&vtProp);
        ///////////////////////////////////
        // Accessing properties

        // hr = pclsObj->Get(SysAllocString(L"NumberOfCores"), 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        
        hr = pclsObj->Get(SysAllocString(L"Name"), 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);

        if(FAILED(hr))
        {
            cout<< "failed"; // it doesn't fail with either property.
            return 0;
        }

        wcout << " Name : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl; <-this line throws the exception.

        ///////////////////////////////////

        VariantClear(&vtProp);
        pclsObj->Release();
    }
```

I read somewhere that you get this error when the (bstrVal) field is either empty or null, but when I checked it was neither.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the result code here `hr = pclsObj->Get(S ...` ?

Comment: `bstrVal` only works for strings.  `NumberOfCores` is not a string.   Also, you need to free those strings you allocate with `SysAllocString` with `SysFreeString` .  If you have been writing a lot of code like this, then you have a big problem, because it's leaking memory all over the place.

Comment: @Richard FAILED(hr) is false while accessing either property. I'll edit the code and put this in.

Comment: @Matt I tried with another property "SerialNumber" which is a string but I got the same error. This is the only piece of code I've written, thanks for the tip, I'll use `SysFreeString`.

Comment: Old school: `if (V_VT(&vtProp) == VT_BSTR)`. that said, `NumberOfCores` doesn't seem like something that would be reported as a variant property *string*; Rather, it seems like something that would be a `VT_INT`, or a `VT_I4`, or just about any scalar type. Rule of thumb is do not poke into a `VARIANT` until you know the *type* and therefore know which member is actually set. Unrelated, those `SysAllocString` calls are leaking memory like a sieve leaks rainwater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm accessing the wrong property of the VARIANT object.
Instead of "bstrVal", I should access "uintVal" because the property "NumberOfCores" is an unsigned int not a BSTR object.